# Usage of "for" and "to"

Tags: word-usage

Sometimes I get confused about when to use for and to.

Example, should I say

> For me, this is the best option.

or

> To me, this is the best option.

Comment: This is a difficult question.  They're largely the same, but I see results in COCA where swapping *to* and *for* sounds wrong (or at least unnatural).  I wasn't sure how to answer this the last time I saw someone ask it, and I'm still not sure how...

Comment: I'll say this [again](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8603/confusion-regarding-in-on-and-at/8605#comment14165_8605); most prepositions have several (if not more) usages. Some of them overlap; some of them are idiomatic. Asking: _When should we use Preposition A vs Preposition B?_ is going to be **too broad**, as both words will have a myriad of uses, and some of them (like the one you mention in this question) will overlap. "To" and "for" can be looked up in the dictionary. If you have a **specific** question, that's fine, but a general "I get confused between A and B" is too broad.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you had asked the community to describe the difference in meaning (if any) between, "For me, this is the best option," and "To me, this is the best option," that would be acceptable, because that's a specific question. However, the way you have couched this, the "_for me_ vs. _to me_" question is just a token example within a much larger inquiry – when to use _for_, and when to use _to_. That question is too broad and thus not answerable.

Comment: @alexchenco Could you please clarify whether you intended the question the way J.R. has interpreted it?  I thought you were asking specifically about *"For me, [...]"* versus *"To me, [...]"*.  Is that the case?

Comment: @snailboat: Could be. If your interpretation turns out to be the more accurate one, this question could easily be fixed up, and I'd have no qualms about reopening it.